# The action 'news' could not be found for UsersController

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I am doing Chapter 7 of Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial and when in section 7.2 I want to create a sign up form. This is my users_controller.rb code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
 @user = User.new
  end
end
```

and here is my show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
<aside class="col-md-4">
<section class="user_info">
  <h1>
    <%= gravatar_for @user %>
    <%= @user.name %>
  </h1>
</section>
</aside>
</div>
```

Comment: You are referring to a `news` method while your method is called `new`.

Comment: @GhostGambler I am new in ruby on rails, but I do just michel hartle said in his book! https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up section 7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Narges we understand that you are following Michael Hartle's book however in all publications related to programming there are usually typo's in the text. Like @GhostGambler said you are calling 'news' somewhere and your method is called 'new'. This is what is causing your error, news is not in your code anywhere and you are calling it. Find where it is being called and replace it with 'new' and you will see the error go away and your code to produce the wanted results.

Comment: Thank you! I can find my mistake in config/router.rb ->  get 'signup'  => 'users#news' , erase extra 's' and now it works!